# solving heat equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the
`

```
Eqn := D[theta[x], {x, 2}] + 
   D[theta[x], x] + \[Beta]*(D[theta[x], x])^2 - N1^2*theta[x] + Q1 - 
   G1*theta[x]^3 == 0;`
```

with parameters

```
N1 = 0.5; G1 = 0.2; \[Beta] = 2
```

as

```
sol[Q1_] := 
 First@NDSolve[{D[theta[x], {x, 2}] + 
      D[theta[x], x] + \[Beta]*(D[theta[x], x])^2 - N1^2*theta[x] + 
      Q1 - G1*theta[x]^3 == 0, theta[0] == 1, theta'[1] == 0}, 
   theta, {x, 0, 1}]
```

and plot it as
`

```
Plot[{Evaluate[theta[x] /. sol[0]], 
  Evaluate[theta[x] /. sol[0.2]]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {X, \[Theta][X]}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[Framed@
    LineLegend[{Continous, Dashed}, {"Q1=0.0", "Q1=0.2"}, 
     LabelStyle -> {Bold, 12}, LegendMarkerSize -> {45, 10}], {Right, 
    Top}]]
`
```

Now I want to solve and plot the following equation how can I plot it

> q=(1+)/.

Answer (score 4):

```
  q=(1+)/x
```

Since everything is known in the RHS. Just need to evaluate this

```
Clear["Global`*"]
N1 = 1/2; G1 = 2/10; beta = 2; 

ode = D[theta[x], {x, 2}] + D[theta[x], x] + beta*(D[theta[x], x])^2 -
     N1^2*theta[x] + Q1 - G1*theta[x]^3 == 0;

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, theta[0] == 1, theta'[1] == 0}, 
   theta, {x, 0, 1}, {Q1}];

Plot[{sol[0][1], sol[0.2][x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {X, \[Theta][X]}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]

(*pick value say Q1=1 for the solution parameter to evaluate q *)
q = (1 + beta*sol[1][x])*D[sol[1][x],x]

Plot[q, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, I do not know why you call this the "heat equation". It does not look like one for me.